# Как запускать junit тест из браузера FF с сохраненным паролем?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

Через eclipse запускаю JUnit тест при помощи geckodriver, открывается браузер firefox версии 50.1 чистый, без плагинов, без сохраненного входа на сайт. Как сделать так, чтобы тесты запускались в моем рабочем браузере?

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class InstSubs {

  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/eclipse/selenium/geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://*****.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Копируете папку вашего профиля в папку FF с именем myprofile2222111.

Вариант 1:
В параметры запуска FF вписываете -profile myprofile2222111

Вариант 2:
Переименовываете firefox.exe в firefox1.exe
создаёте .bat файл с содержимым

```
start firefox.exe -profile myprofile2222111
```

при помощи battoexeconverter превращаете ваш .bat в .exe кладёте в папку FF с именем firefox.exe

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. попробовал второй вариант- получилась зацикленность. firefox.exe запускает firefox.exe. если перед компиляцией батника в ехе указать start firefox1.exe ..., то вручную запускается как хотелось, а geckodriver при запуске теста не находит firefox1.exe

Про параметры запуска не нагуглил, можно чуть подробней что Вы имели в виду?